# Finitely Generated R-mod category is not finitely complete.

Tags: category-theory

I'd like to prove the fact that the Finitely Generated  R-mod category is not finitely complete, and to give an additional condition to R so that this category could be finitely complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the direct sum of finitely generated modules is finitely generated, the only thing that could possibly go wrong is that there is some homomorphism between finitely generated modules that does not have a finitely generated kernel. I leave it to you to translate this to a condition on $R$...

Comment: You mean that it has binary products, but not equalizers. But equalizer doesn't have to be a kernel necessarily, right?

Comment: Equalisers are also kernels in an additive category.

Comment: @CarlosVázquezMonzón The equalizer of $f$ and $g$ is the kernel of $f-g$ (and conversely).